# Bold the first sentence of divs with the same name

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

Im using Facebook Feed plugin for WordPress. I want bold first sentence from each post. For now script bolding first sentence from first post. The second one is still the same.

```
<script>
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.cff-text');
divs.forEach(function(div) {
    var divText = div.textContent;
    var sentences = divText.split('. ');

    if (sentences.length > 0) {
        var firstSentence = sentences[0];
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(firstSentence, '<span style="font-size: 15px;">' + firstSentence + '</span>');
    }
});
```

enter image description here
[image]
[image]